# xcode make a install package witl library

Tags: xcode, macos, package

i am new in code, i made a little application:
simple webbrowser with webkit framewark.

The question is.. how can i made a installer package for mac osx and be sure that when i install this package on another mac should be all ok with necessary files and/or framework?

Maybe the question is stupid but i come from windows and delphi, where if you not include dll in project in exe's directory, the program does not work....

thank  a lot.

p.s. i see from xcode: archive, export as, mac installer package... have i to do this or exist other ways?.... in that way seem i need a identities, but i have only Ios indentifie and not Osx identitie and i think i can not use that.... is it right?

Comment: You do not create installers on OS X (only for some few things, so in general every app on a Mac is "portable"). If you go to `Archive`->`Export` choose to export as a normal app. Everything you need to run the app is bundeled within the .app package. You can run the app on every Mac that is supported by your deployment target (OS X 10.8 or whatever you chose).

Comment: oh, thanks a lot, so i can make only archive export as application... and i can get only that file .app? and it work on other mac without other files?.it's very very small, only 300k... is it normal?

Comment: Yes. (or you *can* export it as an installer but users hate to install stuff instead of just dragging and dropping it around wherever they want to have it). And yes, everything you need is inside the .app bundle. :)

Comment: ok,thanks a lot, this is super respect windows programs :-), but if i would to export it as installer how can i make it?...^_^ i need identities for mac osx?.on site developer.apple.com i see that i have only ios identity.. thatnks a lot and sorry for all.

Comment: An installer doesn't require you to have a certificate as far as I know. If you really want to create one you would go to Archive -> Export -> Installer just as you did.

Comment: I m so sorry but i can't make it. i make this on xcode: menu product->archive. it show me a list with all archive... i chose the button distribute, and show me a window where a can choose:submit to the mac app store,- export developer id-signed application, - export as.....so i choose export as and i can choose between xcode archive, application or Mac installer package...if i choose application it go well and create me the .app file...but if i choose MAc installer package, it show me a window where say me to choose for identities and i cant go forward.maybe that you mean is not this function

Comment: Yes, that is the option you need. It seems that you need a certificate for creating an installer package.

Comment: sorry, i have another question... this is the last :)...i tried the .app on another mac and when i try to open it ... say me that the app is not verified... or something similar... so for run i have to click right button and then open it.... is posible to run without that message?... thank a lot one more time

Comment: Yes, you have to sign it with a valid certificate. You can get one once you registered a payed account at developer.apple.com. This process is needed as part of OS X Gatekeeper. If an app contains malicious code and Apple knows that it will update a blacklist and the app won't start on any system anymore (this is a guess, it could  also only be a warning, but Apple is very aggressive in deactivating malicious software).

Comment: i'm trying but i cant, i try to explain, i have iOS developer program, but i think i need Mac developer program also, but when i go on my develepor.apple.com profile i cant buy that: i go to choose mac dev program, and when i choose it, the system show me only ios program, but i have it.

Comment: Have you tried the following link? https://developer.apple.com/programs/mac/ Just click enroll.

Comment: yes.. it's that link that i tried i click there.. after i choose my id apple... i choose company profile and then he show me onli ios dev and i cant make nothing, i have tried also create a new id apple but the system tell me an error. maybe is better i go to write apple dev suport... thanks a lot, you are very kindly.I appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: Oh okay, alright, you're welcome 